# The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created)

Tags: python, selenium

So my script for some reason is now giving me the current errors when i run it. Its a selenium project that opens a browser headless.It was working just fine.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50010/devtools/browser/a0bd7321-8810-4867-9a1a-44830cabb881
[0531/093705.662:INFO:CONSOLE(483)] "The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio", source: https://thesite/TSPD/082a057379ab2000e04675d6650b7d08e00fa87e834636f3276a953aff91cafadccfc9f4abbb23b7?type=8 (483)
[0531/093705.665:INFO:CONSOLE(483)] "The ScriptProcessorNode is deprecated. Use AudioWorkletNode instead. (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/audio-worklet)", source: https://thesite/TSPD/082a057379ab2000e04675d6650b7d08e00fa87e834636f3276a953aff91cafadccfc9f4abbb23b7?type=8 (483)
[0531/093705.668:INFO:CONSOLE(487)] "The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio", source: https://thesite/TSPD/082a057379ab2000e04675d6650b7d08e00fa87e834636f3276a953aff91cafadccfc9f4abbb23b7?type=8 (487)
[0531/093705.668:INFO:CONSOLE(488)] "The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio", source: https://thesite/TSPD/082a057379ab2000e04675d6650b7d08e00fa87e834636f3276a953aff91cafadccfc9f4abbb23b7?type=8 (488)
[0531/093705.669:ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(225)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
```

Im going to call the site "thesite" cause its private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer to the ERROR and FOR THE INFO:CONSOLE.

For the ERROR i just added :

```
options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
```

and for the INFO:CONSOLE:

```
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
```